# Enemy attack the player?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created an enemy to attack a player, this enemy has a gun. I want when this gun shot, the shot goes to direction of player. I can instantiate but can't change direction bullet to attack my player in his position.

how can I do this ?

I'm trying this.

```
public class EnemyShotGun : MonoBehaviour {

     public GameObject[] gun; //gun attack player
     public GameObject prefabShot; //shot
     public float enemyShotSpeed;
     private float delayAttack; 
     public float timeAttack; 

     //player
     private Transform player;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("AirPlane").transform;
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {
         delayAttack += Time.deltaTime;
         if (delayAttack >= timeAttack){            
             for(int x = 0; x < gun.Length; x++){
                 GameObject shot = Instantiate(prefabShot, gun[x].transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                 shot.rigidbody2D.AddRelativeForce(new Vector2(0, -500)); 
                 shot.transform.position = player.position; //bullet goes to player position
             }                        
             delayAttack = 0;
         }

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to add force towards player. Not towards -Y direction. So change this:

```
             shot.rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, -500));
```

to something like this:

```
             shot.rigidbody2D.AddForce(((Vector2)(player.position - shot.transform.position)).normalized * 500);
```

in which `player.position - shot.transform.position` is a vector from the shot to the player.

also remove this line:

```
             shot.transform.position = player.position; //bullet goes to player position
```

It is moving the shot to the player position immediately.

Comment: the line `shot.rigidbody2D.AddForce((player.position - shot.transform.position).magnitude * 500);` 

see: http://i.imgur.com/mxYxVcn.png

Comment: I was supposed to normalize the vector, so that the force is not dependent on the distance, but I accidentally wrote `magnitude` instead of `normalized`.